# How to tell Maven2 to execute jUnit tests one by one each in new JVM instance?

Tags: maven-2, junit, jvm

Is it possible to tell Maven2 to execute every jUnit test in new JVM instance (fork) in serial mode, i.e. one by one.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have to fork the JVM like explained [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#forkMode)

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.9</version>
  <configuration>
    <forkMode>always</forkMode>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

It should also be possible by just declaring a Sytem property

```
mvn -DforkMode=always test
```

As described in the documentation: *"always" forks for each test-class*. I do not know if the "*pertest*" setting will fork for each test.

---

Thanks to @Djebel for pointing out that `forkMode` is deprecated now. There is a detailed documentation on "[Fork Options and Parallel Test Execution](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html)" and how to use the new parameters [`forkCount`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#forkCount) and [`reuseForks`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#reuseForks) and that also includes the following migration tips:

```
Old Setting                         New Setting
forkMode=once (default)             forkCount=1 (default), reuseForks=true (default)
forkMode=always                     forkCount=1 (default), reuseForks=false
forkMode=never                      forkCount=0
forkMode=perthread, threadCount=N   forkCount=N, (reuseForks=false, if you did not had that one set)
```

Comment: Of note, `forkMode` is now deprecated, [reuseForks](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#reuseForks) should be used instead

Answer (score 2):

What about the standard `forkMode` option? Does it run the tests in parallel as opposed to serial as you want it?

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <forkMode>always</forkMode>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well i tried these responses but what i just got was several test functions of a same JUnit test running at the same time. For creating a JVM for each JUnit Test files (what i needed) you must use the folowing configuration (The difference it the `parallel` parameter):

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration> 
            <parallel>classes</parallel>
            <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
            <includes> 
                <include>**/*Test.java</include>     
            </includes> 
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Replace the mattern `**/*Test.java` for one that matches those JUnit Tests that must run in different JVMs. For more information visit: [Combining forkCount and parallel](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html#Combining_forkCount_and_parallel).