# CDI classpath issue using maven and embedded glassfish

Tags: jpa, maven, classpath, cdi, surefire

I'm having an issue with injecting an `EntityManager` from a `Producer` in the test source to a service in the main source.  The intent is to embed this library into another project where the project would define a `Producer` using it's own `PersistenceContext` unitName.  If I don't have a Producer in the main sources, I get `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName MY_PU` error.

For example:

```
/** src/main/java/org/sample/service */
@Stateless
public class MyBean {
    @Inject
    @MyCustomQualifier
    private EntityManager em;
}


/** src/test/java/org/sample/service */
public class EntityManagerProducer {
    @Produces
    @MyCustomQualifier
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MY_PU")
    private EntityManager em;
}
```

In order for me to test the service, I have to use the maven ant plugin to move the *.class file to the `target/classes` dir and remove it before the package phase.  This works but it's kludgy.  I've tried changing the `<useSystemClassLoader>` and `<useManifestOnlyJar>` params in the surefire plugin with no success.

Is there another way?

My environment

- Maven: 2.2.1
- Surefire: 2.4.2
- glassfish-embedded-all: 3.1.1

**EDIT**

beans.xml exists in both (test/main)/resources/META-INF

I'm starting the GF container as follows.

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
properties.put(EJBContainer.MODULES, new File[]{new File("target/classes"), new File("target/test-classes")});
EJBContainer ejbContainer = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(properties);
Context ctx = ejbContainer.getContext();
MyBean service = ctx.lookup("java:global/ejb-app/classes/MyBean");
```

Comment: Sounds like the libraries and classes in the project are conflicting with what glassfish is loading. I've never had great luck with embedded containers and maven because maven doesn't keep the classpaths clean. What happens if you spin up glassfish in a new vm?

Comment: @LightGuard: By default, surefire forkMode is `once`.  So the embedded container should be in a separate JVM from maven.  [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813373/how-to-tell-maven2-to-execute-junit-tests-one-by-one-each-in-new-jvm-instance)

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't see the problem at all ^^

Do you have a 
src/test/resources/META-INF/beans.xml?

And how does your test look like? Arquillian, or do you start the container manually?
Do you have the persistence.xml with the MY_PU PersistenceUnit in the classpath? Any github or so where I can look at the sample project?

I need a bit more info about your environment to help you...

Comment: I'm not using Arquillian.  Simple `EJBContainer.createEJBContainer()` (note edit above). Yes, persistence.xml exists in the classpath. Sorry, no github.

Comment: Troy, can you please try 

Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MY_PU").createEntityManager() ?

If this works, then we can try further steps.
If this already gives you an invalid EM or none at all, then there is something wrong with your JPA installation or with your persistence.xml.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem and downgraded to Maven 3.0.5.

It appears the issue is discussed in [this Glassfish JIRA](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20802).  I couldn't seem to find the Maven JIRA that is mentioned in the discussion.  I'm still looking for a way to use the latest Maven with embedded Glassfish, but haven't had much luck.

Answer (score 0):

Eeesh! I had forgotten about this post. Thank you to everyone who provided input. IIRC, we ended up dropping the embedded container in favor of external GF container using Arquillian. At the time, I think we felt it provided a more realistic test environment and avoided the class loading issues with the embedded container.